# how to make 'makefile"? Compile Error

Tags: linux, makefile, hook

```
obj-m += interceptor.o
all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean


make: make nothing to be done for all <---error
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are those `make -C` lines indented with a tab in the makefile?

Comment: I think they must be, because if they weren't make will show some sort of syntax error such as "missing separator" or something.  The fact that it says "nothing to do" means it fully and correctly parsed the makefile.

Comment: Do you have a file named `all` in your directory where you're invoking make?  If you do then you'd get a message like this, because the `all` file already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a tab (must be a tab, not spaces) before line 3 and line 5, like:

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

**DO NOT COPY DIRECTLY** from the sample above, since the tab I typed has been converted to spaces by Stackoverflow.

Comment: @LaserFrame Would you mind upvoting and accepting this answer if it does help? :)